# Is it possible to overwrite the window.location.hostname value in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a way to fool a web page, more precisely a js module in spanking it to believe that it is on another domain name. I documented myself and I came across pkusieur forum which spoke of overwrite the variable `window.location.hostname`. I unfortunately did not find any answer to my question. Did I orient myself well? Can somebody solve my problem?
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**
I can use explorer like firfox or chrome or use a spécifique python module for create a appilcation can do this.

Comment: Presumably yes, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location lists only `origin` as read-only. You may consider describing the problem what you face, as it unlikely started as "Uh, I have to overwrite window.location.hostname!". Are you looking for some redirection code perhaps?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to change it. Neither `window.location` nor `window.location.hostname` are monkeypatchable, at least in Chrome. But I'm sure there's another way. Is the page you want the script to run on your own site, or someone else's?

Comment: On my website CertainPerformance, but in use a external js module.

Comment: Put @ before a username to ping them, else they won't see your message. If it's on your site, consider just copying the script source and making the required changes to it, then hosting and serving the modified script, instead of linking to the original.

Comment: My goal is not to redirect but I want to stay on www.example.com but the js import code is veiled www.fakeSite.com @tevemadar.

Comment: Oh yes, you will need to build an unsecure browser that's open to abuse, for this to work.

Comment: @Hackinet It's not a probleme because his goal is to visit my website only.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying `window.location.xy` results in page-reload:

```js
console.log(window.location.hostname);
console.log(window.location.hostname="example.com");
console.log(window.location.hostname);
```

(In the JS console you can see that the value remains unchanged for the snippet itself, but then the page reloads from example.com)

> My goal is not to redirect but I want to stay on www.example.com but the js import code is veiled www.fakeSite.com @tevemadar.

I think you would need to change `origin` for that, and it is the only read-only part of [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) exactly for making that impossible. You want to circumvent CORS to my understanding.
I do not suggest using it, but if you desperately need some hack to test something, check https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @tevemadarThank you for your complex explanation but the problem is not to be able to go everywhere but to make the site believe that it is running on a site with a customizable domain name.

Comment: @TraqueurRush *make the site believe that it is running on a site with a customizable domain name* - what part of the site needs that? Perhaps there is another way. `Location` is something what the user sees too, and that is why you can not alter it without also navigating to another page (otherwise it would be a tool for phising and similar attacks)

Comment: No it's not for attacks !

Comment: @TraqueurRush I do not say you want anything bad, just the same functionality could be used for an attack, and that is why you can't do it for legit purposes either.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly change `window.location.hostname`, however doing so will cause the browser to actually navigate to the new URL.

You can't have window.location reflect a value that isn't the actual location of the browser.

Comment: And if i create my own explorer with python3, can it's work ?

Comment: Create your own explorer?

Comment: Like in pyqt5, we can use a widget can request a website, so did the widget can change this ? https://pythonspot.com/pyqt5-webkit-browser/

Comment: I mean, in theory, you could write software with a custom JavaScript interpreter that *doesn't follow the standard* and thus has a fake window.location.hostname value. Then you could write JavaScript that uses that workaround to do something with whatever library you're working with. But that sounds like an awful lot of trouble given the circumstances. It's almost an absurd tree to bark up.